# fails to fetch max(math) result from database using php code

Tags: php, mysql

I have written this code in get.php

```
<?php
include 'in.php';
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(math) AS math FROM Persons");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$h = $row['math'];
echo "The Highest marks in Math is: $h";

?>
```

database details are in in.php;
but get.php gives no result only "The Highest marks in Math is: " ...but no marks is coming... can anyone say why this code fails to retrieve max result from the database.. is there any wrong in this code...?? here is my url where i am writing my project... -> http://isure.tk/p/php/get.php

Comment: Try `SELECT MAX(math) AS math`

Comment: yes! it is solved! i tried SELECT "MAX(math) AS math" now and it gives the highest mark.. thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you not use mysql_fetch_array()  Function after create query.

Just i pest new code here.

```
<?php
include 'in.php';
$q = intval($_GET['q']);  // No required of this line.
$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT MAX(math) AS math FROM Persons");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$h = $row['math'];
echo "The Highest marks in Math is: $h";
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your column name is `MAX(math)`, not `math`.

Try:

```
"SELECT MAX(math) as `result` FROM Persons"
```

Note also that you are not fetching the result (ie. you aren't defining `$row` to be the result row). Once that's done, you can access `$row['result']` - aliases are useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(math) as math FROM Persons");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$h = $row['math'];
echo "The Highest marks in Math is: $h";
```

Answer (score 0):

you didnt fetch your results.

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(math) as math FROM Persons");
  $row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $h = $row['math'];
```